# Rails Devise Strange behaviour with foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a simple User & Address Model.

I've created a nested form that has an address model nested into the User model. My User Model has the devise attributes etc.

It all works fine, except that there's a strange behaviour happening when the user is created.

If you read below, you'll notice the "user_id" which is the address of the owning user is populated when the record is first committed. But then immediately afterward, something that looks like it's in Devise core, is resetting the user_id to null.

Does anyone know what would be causing this?

> Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-03 22:45:20 +1100
>   Processing by Member::UsersController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"Pr8lSEJalWwosuaLPOrYqQ+sOkFCyoNujaUybxpZDAg=",
>   "user"=>{"address_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"HOlley",
>   "last_name"=>"Hou"}, "email"=>"HollyHou@hisense.com.au",
>   "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
>   Creating a new user    (0.1ms)  BEGIN    (0.1ms)  COMMIT    (0.0ms) 
>   BEGIN   Member::User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM
>   `member_users` WHERE `member_users`.`email` = BINARY
>   'hollyhou@hisense.com.au' LIMIT 1   SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO
>   `member_users` (`created_at`, `current_sign_in_at`,
>   `current_sign_in_ip`, `email`, `encrypted_password`,
>   `last_sign_in_at`, `last_sign_in_ip`, `remember_created_at`,
>   `reset_password_sent_at`, `reset_password_token`, `sign_in_count`,
>   `updated_at`) VALUES ('2012-11-03 11:45:20', NULL, NULL,
>   'hollyhou@hisense.com.au',
>   '$2a$10$1JvC/sO85L2esNp8xA9qseTc78.rtOyF3zSBi/fOTiWJRt9.zgYha', NULL,
>   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '2012-11-03 11:45:20')   SQL (0.2ms) 
>   INSERT INTO `member_addresses` (`address3`, `address_1`, `address_2`,
>   `address_type`, `business_name`, `city`, `country`, `created_at`,
>   `first_name`, `geo_late`, `geo_long`, `is_primary`, `last_name`,
>   `middle_name`, `phone1`, `phone1_type`, `phone2`, `phone2_type`,
>   `postcode`, `primary_email`, `secondary_email`, `state`, `status`,
>   `suburb`, `title`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-11-03 11:45:20', 'HOlley', NULL, NULL,
>   NULL, 'Hou', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-11-03 11:45:20', 5)    (1.3ms)  COMMIT
>   (0.1ms)  BEGIN    (0.2ms)  UPDATE `member_users` SET `last_sign_in_at`
>   = '2012-11-03 11:45:20', `current_sign_in_at` = '2012-11-03 11:45:20', `last_sign_in_ip` = '127.0.0.1', `current_sign_in_ip` = '127.0.0.1',
>   `sign_in_count` = 1, `updated_at` = '2012-11-03 11:45:20' WHERE
>   `member_users`.`id` = 5    (0.2ms)  COMMIT    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
>   (0.2ms)  UPDATE `member_addresses` SET `user_id` = NULL, `updated_at`
>   = '2012-11-03 11:45:20' WHERE `member_addresses`.`id` = 5    (0.2ms)  COMMIT

The controller is a custom controller because I eventually (once I get this working), need to be able to redirect to 2 different places after registration depending where the customer logged in from (checkout or header in this case).

```
class Member::UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super
  end

  def new
    super
  end

  def edit
    Rails.logger.debug { "Editing the user" }
    super
  end

  def show
    Rails.logger.debug { "Showing the user controller" }
  end
end
```

and from routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users, :class_name => "Member::User", :controllers => {:registrations => 'member/users', :sessions => 'member/sessions'}
```

Comment: Are you using a custom controller or the basic one that devise provides ?

Comment: Custom controller, but the controller at this stage is just calling "super". I'll post it on the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. It was actually related to an answer I got from a previous question regarding nested form.

In this code below, previously in the nested address field, I was always calling build_address and because address is one to one relationship when the form was refreshing it was creating a new address. Now I think it should be ok, I haven't tested it, but at least the address nullification problem is resolved.

> resource_name,:url =>
>   registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class =>
>   'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
>               Mandatory fields marked *
>                "alert alert-error", :id => "flash_error") if flash[:error] %>
>                "flash_notice") if flash[:notice] %>
>                "alert alert-error", :id => "flash_alert") if flash[:alert] %>
>               
>               
>               
>                   
>                    {:class => "input-xlarge"} %>
>                    {:class => "input-xlarge"} %>
>
> ```
>         <%= f.input :email, :input_html => {:class => "input-xlarge"} %>
>         <%= f.input :password, :required => true, :input_html => {:class => "input-xlarge"}   %>
>         <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true, :input_html => {:class => "input-xlarge"} %>
>         <div class="form-actions">
>           <%= f.button :submit, "Register", :class => "btn btn-success btn-large" %>
>         </div>
>     <% end %>
> ```